# Powershell script try catch out-file report inconsistent

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I'm having inconsistent result when it comes to out-file report form a try catch loop.

this is the script I'm using

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:White;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:Grey}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:White}"
$a = $a + "</style>"
$web = Get-Content 'websites.txt'
$servers = Get-Content 'servers.txt' 

$servers | foreach-object  -process {ICM -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { 
$using:web | foreach-object $_ {$propertiestest = @{
                                ServerName = $using:_
                                Webtest = $_
                                Success = $C
                                Error_Code = $B}
try {

    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($_)
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
$C = Write-output "Success"
   } catch {
$B = Write-output ("FAILED!!! The error was $_") 
} finally {

    if ($response) {
        $response.Close()
        Remove-Variable response 

    }
} 
New-Object PSObject -Property $propertiestest}}}
```

The result is something like this:

```
ServerName     : someserver
Webtest        : some web site
Error_Code     : 
Success        : Success
```

Sometimes i get error_code AND success at the same time and sometimes i don't get any of them at all.

Any input will be appreciated

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but try creating your $propertiestest after your if statement at the end of the script block instead of at the beginning of the script block

Comment: Right, what @AnthonyStringer says seems good, because you are assigning $properties at the top of the loop, the first time through there will be no value for $C and $B, then the loop body runs and either $C or $B is set, and you use that at the top of the next loop. Then you run over another server and set either $C or $B again - here you could start the top of a new loop with both $C and $C set, both from previous runs, both from different previous runs. This also implies your error_code and success are always matched with the wrong ServerName.

Comment: That actually worked for the blank returns. thanks a lot for that. i'm still getting error_code AND success for the ones that have an error code

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the cmdlet [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh849901.aspx) , that way you'll have better control of request's behavior in your script and won't have to worry about closing the response. Look at the "ErrorAction" parameter too, with that you can define if the script should continue or not in case of error.